# Google Places Autocomplete boundaries doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using the Google Maps Places API for JavaScript, and set my boundaries to **Berlin, Germany**.

This is my code (I am using a npm-module for it, but as you see in the console.log, the bounds are getting passed correctly):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Autocomplete from 'react-google-autocomplete';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ReactDOM.render(<Autocomplete
        style={{width: '90%'}}
        onPlaceSelected={(place) => {
          console.log(place);
        }}
        types={[]}
        bounds={new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                      new window.google.maps.LatLng(51.2, 13.41),
                      new window.google.maps.LatLng(52.5200, 10.40)
                    )}
      />, document.getElementById('mount'));
});
```

Now, when I try to search for a place nearby, it delivers me a place in India first and then Berlin:

**Without the word Berlin:**
[image]

**With the word Berlin:**
[image]

**My boundaries are set to Berlin:**
[image]

> So my question is now: Is this behaviour normal or did I get something
>   wrong? I tried to switch the LatLng just out of curiosity, but same
>   result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting `strictBounds` to `true` to limit the results to just the bounds. Otherwise you are favouring that area but results can come from outside.

From the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete):

- bounds is a google.maps.LatLngBounds object specifying the area in which to search for places. The results are biased towards, but not restricted to, places contained within these bounds.
- strictBounds is a boolean specifying whether the API must return only those places that are strictly within the region defined by the given bounds. The API does not return results outside this region even if they match the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Use these bounds:

```
new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.35, 13.1),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.65, 13.8),
)
```